# extract json from json string

Tags: java, json

I am fetching data from the database as a JSON String:

```
{"companyName":"abcd","address":"abcdefg"}
```

How can I extract the company name from the given JSON String?

Comment: Do you mean `how to work with JSON in Java`? It seems unclear what you are asking about. I made this assumption only because of `java` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer [JSON](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
JSONObject companyName = jsonObject .get("companyName");
```

Comment: Although you did provide a link to some javadoc, you didn't explain that this requires installing a third-party jar file in order to work, or where to find such file.

Comment: You can download the code from [Here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) compile it and create a jar. Adding this jar should make these classes available.

Answer (score 2):

```
JsonParser parser =  new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse("your string");
JsonObject jsonObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
String comapnyName = jsonObj.get("companyName").getAsString();
```

This is how we can parse json string in java. You will need to add `com.google.gson` library to compile this code.

Comment: There is no `JsonParser` is the Java Standard Library. This code won't compile.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for remind me. I have updated the library.

Answer (score 2):

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

```
  obj.put("name","foo");
  obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
  obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
  obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));

  StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
  obj.writeJSONString(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("{\"companyName\":\"abcd\", \"address\":\"abcdefg\"}");
System.out.println("companyName=" + json.get("companyName"));
System.out.println("address=" + json.get("address"));
```

Comment: The question is about Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: I have edited my answer ,I think this Gonna work